# What solutions to use QGIS as insert tool for a Postgres relationnal database?

Tags: qgis, postgis, pyqgis

I have a Postgres/PostGIS relational database and I would like to use QGIS as an interface for inserting data. The thing is that my database is quite complex and I need my tool to handle the following features: one-to-many relations, point coordinates editing and *guided insert*.

What I call *guided insert* is the procedure of inserting a line in a table, then inserting one or more lines in a child table with the foreign key of the first line, etc ... I need this feature to work with up to 4 levels (ex: insert a country, then a city related to this country, then a building related to this city and finally a person related to this building)

I see three solutions that could potentially fit my need, but before going into further tests and investigations, I would like to benefit from other experiences.

**1) Using the QGIS Forms with relations between the tables:**

This is the first thing I tried. It works not so bad, except from some difficulties with foreign keys legacy and coordinates editing. I just fear that it might not be customizable enough for all my use cases.

**2) Using a custom from with QtDesigner:**

As I never really used QtDesigner, I am not really sure of its potential in my case but it seems to be a good candidate for more customizable forms.

**3) Using pygis:**

I know a bit of Python, but I never used it to develop tools for QGIS. I think it might be the appropriate tool, especially in terms of customizability but I fear the development time compared to the other solutions.

Does someone have an idea of what could be the most appropriate tool?

**QGIS :** 2.10

**Postgres:** 9.3

**PostGIS:** 2.1.7

Answer (score 1):

I know it is a bit late but it might still help. The best is to use the following;

- PyQt using Model View Framework
- PostgreSQL with PostGIS
- SQLAlchemy with Geo-alchemy to link PyQt with the db.
- QGIS as a container of all GUI and with a visualization feature.
- PyQGIS to do the work related to visualization and QGIS GUI related tasks.

So in short, you need to create a QGIS plugin using the above tools.